# where is the fvmro8r sourcefile? Tufte-latex example

Tags: fonts, tufte

I was testing the `tufte-latex` sample-book.tex example (copied and pasted character for character) but it produced the following error:

```
    !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file fvmro8r): Font fvmro8r at 612 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Up until that point all was going well with some 30 pages produced but then the above occurred and no output produced.

I have the Bera source file downloaded and extracted into the right place in my directories, but the fvmro8r doesn't appear there (only fvmro8a, fvmro8b).

Does anyone know where I can find this source file? Are there any specific instructions into its placement n the directory...

I'm using MikTex 2.9 on windows7 with either TeXmaker or TeXnicCenter (if that matters)...

Comment: You didn't activate the map-file. Your description is a bit unclear. If you used the package manager to install the fonts you probably have map-files in your user account and so need to run in a terminal `updmap` to update them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This worked thanks very much, thought I had updated everything...could you post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't activate the map-file. Your description is a bit unclear. If you used the package manager to install the fonts you probably have map-files in your user account and so need to run in a terminal `updmap` to update them.

Answer (score 0):

.../fonts/tfm/public/bera/fvmro8r.tfm

Comment: Thanks, that's where they are! I suppose I was a bit unclear as Ulrike said, LaTeX couldn't find the fonts but now having run `updmap` all is ok.